# Dart Double Decimal after Multiple additions

Tags: dart, double, decimal

When trying to run the following snippet:

```
void main() {
      double step = 0.1;
      double currentAmount = 1;
            while (currentAmount < 2) {
              currentAmount = currentAmount + step;
              print (currentAmount);
            }
    }
```

The output is as follows:

```
1.1
1.2000000000000002
1.3000000000000003
1.4000000000000004
1.5000000000000004
1.6000000000000005
1.7000000000000006
1.8000000000000007
1.9000000000000008
2.000000000000001
```

Can anybody tell me why the decimals are appearing as such and is this the normal behavior?

Comment: Check explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/5061381)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are losing precision
have a look at this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal), it should solve your problem